# Configuring devise to send emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, devise

I wrote a custom mailer that sends an email whenever a user receives a notification.
for some reason the custom mailer works but the built in devise mailer doesn't work.
I'm not able to send confirmation emails

is something missing in my configuration ?

-devise.rb:

```
 config.mailer_sender = "user@gmail.com"
```

-setup_mail.rb:

```
require "development_mail_interceptor"

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => "gmail.com",
  :user_name            => "usename",
  :password             => "pass",
  :authentication       => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}



ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = true
ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor(DevelopmentMailInterceptor) if Rails.env.development?
```

Comment: What errors/exceptions are you getting?

Comment: None, the development log writes that the email was sent but i never receive it

Comment: Where does it end up then? Does the system ever talk to `smtp.gmail.com` over the network? Can you increase the error logging level somehow?

Comment: how do i monitor the communication between my server and smtp in production ?

Comment: With a network sniffer, for example http://www.tcpdump.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that looking into

> config/initializers/devise.rb

will do the trick for you:

> config.mailer = "Devise::Mailer"

you can uncomment it!

Answer (score 2):

```
This can be helpful. After r&D, the final complete text is below:

# ActionMailer Config in development/production rb file
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  # change to true to allow email to be sent during development
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    domain: "mail.google.com",####important
    authentication: "plain",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
    password: ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I catch an issue today and I spend 5 hours on it.
Devise 's confirmation email cannot work when the confirmation_token relational columns is blank. Well when the columns is null it works well.

```
#this works well
add_column :users, :confirmation_token, :string
add_column :users, :confirmed_at, :datetime
add_column :users, :confirmation_sent_at, :datetime
add_column :users, :unconfirmed_email, :string

#But this cannot work !!!
add_column :users, :confirmation_token, :string, :null => false, :default => ''
add_column :users, :confirmed_at, :datetime, :null => false, :default => '1970-01-01'
add_column :users, :confirmation_sent_at, :datetime, :null => false, :default => '1970-01-01'
add_column :users, :unconfirmed_email, :string, :null => false, :default => ''
```

---

hope help U when catching this issue alike.~